# Framework for storing settings in a database (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

So after considering my options, I've opted to go with a database storage system to store applications settings. Given the fact that these settings will ultimately be changed every so often by the user, I decided implementing them into a database versus a config file (e.g. .ini file). What we're thinking of doing is storing these settings in a key/pair manner. The only trouble I'm having is finding an efficient way to access and write settings into the database.

My question is, are there any frameworks that you may use/heard of that helps to deal with this type of scenario? The only thing I've managed to find is endless discussions about the storage methods along with their pros and cons but nothing related to implementation of these methods.

Comment: Why not just use a simple 2 column table in mysql?

Comment: You will find nothing here but endless discussions of pros and cons of various methods. My suggestion is to pick a framework, learn it, use it - whether it's CakePHP, Symfony, CodeIgniter, Yii, or natively doing things is up to you. This is a very simple task regardless.

Comment: If they are just key-value pairs, then the implementation would consist of trivial `SELECT` and `UPDATE`

Comment: Gee, storing settings in a database that will be changed every so often. Well it doesn't really matter how you store your settings, the "framework" has to be capable of setting and retrieving values by key. Whats underneath it all doesn't really matter. Unless you're asking about performance and expandability, which I didn't read. I guess writing a small library (or even 3 functions) for this purpose would do the trick, no "framework" needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every framework. But. Why do you even need entire FRAMEWORK to just connect to database? Use native PDO included to every PHP installation. Use SQL libraries or plugins. Or consider using XML/CSV/INI files.

Still wanna frameworks that help with database? Here you go:

> Yii
>   Zend
>   Symfony
>   Codeigniter
>   Laravel
>   Fat-Free
>   Kohana
>   CakePHP
>   Joomla

etc

["Full" list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP)